# Event leading to other events

Tags: c#, events

I've got classes like the following, and `eventA` firing may lead to `eventB` firing, which may lead to `eventC` firing:

```
class classA
{
    public event EventHandler eventA;
}

class classB
{
    public event EventHandler eventB;

    public classB(classA passedInA)
    {
        passedInA.eventA += handleEventA;
    }

    void handleEventA(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* do some work */
        if (somethingIsTrue)
        {
            EventHandler handler = eventB;
            if (handler != null) { handler(this, args); }
        }
    }
}

class classC
{
    public event EventHandler eventC;

    public classC(classB passedInB)
    {
        passedInB.eventB += handleEventB;
    }

    void handleEventB(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* do some other work */
        if (somethingElseIsTrue)
        {
            EventHandler handler = eventC;
            if (handler != null) { handler(this, args); }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me like it's pretty logical to do raise events like the above (cause and effect); but yet, something doesn't feel quite right, because the event handling could go on forever if I'm not careful.

In the worst-case scenario, eventA handlers are set to work in their own (new) threads which never die, or take a long time to die, and the threadpool is exhausted.

Is this a proper way to handle causal events?

Comment: did you consider create of new thread, in which `handler()` function will be actually called?

Comment: Could you please add more description for the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to rise events this way it is called chain of responsibility.

http://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html

Just be careful.